# How can I get svg attached by object?

Tags: jquery, html, svg, html-object

Google Chrome v60.0.3112.101, HTML5, jQuery 3.2.1

My `object` element is linked with `svg`-file. This `svg` is displayed without problems on my html page. I try to get `svg` element with jQuery but it found nothing for my both attemptions:

```
$('object').length; // 1
$('svg').length; // 0
$('object > svg').length; // 0
```

this is my html chunk:

```
<object type='text/svg+xml' data='svg/logo.svg'></object>
```

How can I get my `svg` with jQuery?

P.S. I use this method (an external `svg`-file) because my `svg` will be used on many web-pages. Also I use `object` instead of `img` because that `svg` uses an external `css`-file.

Comment: `$('object')` is same as svg, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `contentDocument` property of the `<object>` element.  That'll give you the document object that is the parent of the `<svg>` element.  Then you can use the `documentElement` property of the document object to get the root element of the document, which will be the `<svg>` element.

```
var svg = $("object")[0].contentDocument.documentElement;
```

To visualise that:

```
#document
   <html>            (HTMLDocument)
      <object>       (HTMLObjectElement)   $("object")[0]
         #document   (HTMLDocument)        .contentDocument
            <svg>    (SVGSVGElement)       .documentElement
```

But remember that the SVG won't be accessible until the page has finished loading. So you need to wait for the Window `onload` event.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

  var svg = $("object")[0].contentDocument.documentElement;
  console.log("svg = ",svg);

});
```

Comment: For your code of `svg` getting, I get the error: *Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:25*

Comment: By default, you can only access the content of an `<object>` if it is from the same domain.  If the SVG is from adifferent domain, it will need to be served with the correct CORS header(s).

Comment: My svg is located on the subdirectory.

Comment: For me contentDocument is simply null, there is no dom exception. The svg is in the same folder as the html file and it shows correctly within the object's document.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object, if you add an id

```
<object id="svg" type='text/svg+xml' data='svg/logo.svg'></object>
```

then you can query for the id like this

```
$('#svg')
```